# Multiple models in a createview

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am using form_valid to run some equations on data before committing to the db. One of my equations requires data from a different model than the one my CreateView is based on. Is there a way to pull data from a model different than the model the CreateView is based on?

Model One (referenced in the CreateView):

```
class Plan(models.Model):
    field = models.FloatField()
    growth_percent = models.FloatField()
```

Model Two (it holds another field that has the other argument I need):

```
class Data(models.Model):
    another_arg = models.FloatField()
```

Here's where I am trying to grab 'another_arg' from the second model and pass it as an argument to a function. CreateView in Views.py:

```
class PlanCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = models.Plan
    fields = ['field']

    def form_valid(self, **kwargs):
       self.object = form.save(commit=False)
       form.instance.growth_percent = get_growth_by_percent(form.instance.field, another_arg)
       self.object.save()
```

function that growth_percent is referencing in a services.py file:

```
def get_growth_by_percent(arg1, arg2):
    growth_percent = arg1 * arg2
    return growth_percent_calc
```

Am I going about this right?

Comment: A bit more context is needed from my understanding.  To get the value from Data, you need to write a query on the Data model where you specify which  row you want from the database.  Is there only one row in the data table, or is there some relation you can think of where an instance of Plan would be related to an instance of Data?